# Not able to scrape www.albonazionalegestoriambientali.it website like other website

Tags: python, web-scraping

Why I'm not getting these links? I tried this code and it works on other websites

Here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
urls = 'https://www.albonazionalegestoriambientali.it/Public/ElenchiIscritti#tipoRicerca=2&paginaCorrente=1&risultatiPerPagina=50&sezione=3&provincia=BS&categoria=4-bis'

grab = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(grab.text, 'html.parser')

f = open("test1.txt", "w")

for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    data = link.get('href')
       
    f.write(data)
       
    f.write("\n")
     
f.close()
```

The links I was talking about:
[image]

Comment: You need to login to that website, in order to get those results.

Comment: i'm already logged in, tht's another reason why i can't understand

Comment: Those links are likely to be a result of another XHR call to an API, and you will need to scrape that url - check your Network tab.

Comment: i saw the url changes when i click the button "dettagli" but i still don't get those links, i get only the links on the footer of the page

Comment: @Niccolo'Tomassini how can you be already logged in when not using a session or passing a cookie in that request?

Comment: @SergeyK i don't know onestly, i've already done the login for visualize the list in the image, there's also a reserved area which ask to log again, but i don't thinks it's important for the links i need

Comment: Using `requests.get()` only gives you the static content in the page. Anything dynamically generated by JavaScript won't be there -- if you want true browser-like behavior, you should use a headless browser instead. (Or, better, find the API that the JavaScript is calling, and use that directly).

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.